# Android Continuous line with out user Interaction?

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview

HI All any one have idea of continuous line display with out user interaction in Surface view. i have idea of draw line using finger draw, but i want continuous line with random values.
Any one have idea of this.any Applications and links all are very help full to me.